# Why does everybody use unanchored namespace declarations (i.e. std:: not ::std::)?

Tags: c++, namespaces

It seems to me that using unanchored namespaces is just asking for trouble later when someone puts in a new namespace that happens to have the same name as a root level namespace and mysteriously alters the meaning of a whole lot of programs.  So, why do people always say `std::` instead of `::std::`.  Do they really mean to be saying "I want to use whatever `std` is handy, not the root one."?

Here is an example of what I mean:

In fred/Foo.h:

```
#include <string>

namespace fred {

class Foo {
 public:
   void aPublicMember(const std::string &s);
};

} // end namespace fred
```

In fred/Bar.h:

```
namespace fred {
namespace std {  // A standard fred component

class string { // Something rather unlike the ::std::string
   // ...
};

} // namespace std

class Bar {
 public:
   void aPublicMember(std::string &s);
};

} // namespace fred
```

In oops.cpp:

```
#include <string>
#include "fred/Bar.h"
#include "fred/Foo.h"  // Oops, the meaning of Foo is now different.
```

Is that what people want, or am I missing something?

And maybe you say that you should just never name a namespace `std`.  And that's all well and good, but what about some other root level namespace then?  Should any root level namespace anybody ever defines anywhere always be off-limits for a sub-namespace name?

To clarify, I won't consider any answer that tells me `std` is special because I just used it as an example.  I'm talking about a general issue, and I'm using `std` as a prop to illustrate it, though I do admit it's a rather startling prop.

Comment: FWIW, I just happened to look inside `<memory>` of VS2022, and they actually DO use a macro `_STD` in there which expands to `::std::` and then refer to things like so: `_STD addressof`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The practical reason for unanchored namespaces is that one level of namespaces usually is enough. When it isn't, a second level is usually going to be used for implementation details. And finally, even when using multiple levels, they are still usually specified implicitly from root level. ie. even inside namespace `ns1`, you'd typically refer to `ns1::ns2::foo` instead of `ns2::foo` or `::ns1::ns2::foo`.

So, for these three reasons the `::ns1` form is redundant in normal cases. The only case where I'd consider it would be in submissions to Boost, because as a Boost author I won't know where my software will be used.

Comment: I'm going to accept this one because it's the closest to a real answer.  I think the other one was just voted higher because it was funnier.  :-)  I suspect I should've chosen a different example, or not asked the question in quite the way that I did.

Answer (score 41):

> So, why do people always say std::
>   instead of ::std::

Probably because they never really had problems with ambiguity because of it.

Along the same lines: I never had to include "earth" in my address, and I'm not going to.

You have to draw the line somewhere, and this it is a reasonable assumption that others won't make their own std namespaces, or at least that a library that does won't be very popular. :)

Comment: *chuckle*  Well, if I were living in Andromeda and wanted to refer to someone on Earth, I would likely skip out on 'local group', but I would include 'Milky Way', 'Sol System', and 'Earth'.

Comment: but mankind needs to techno-evolve off this rock before that's a concern

Answer (score 8):

> why do people always say std::

Not always. I use `string` and `using ::std::string`. So nothing bad if there will be `fred::std::string`, because I still use `std::string`. In small cpp-files it could be even `using namespace ::std`. Sample:

```
#include <iostream>
using ::std::string;
//using namespace ::std; // good for small cpp-files

int main()
{
  string s = "sometext"; // no leading ::std
}
```

> you should just never name a namespace std

Yes, you shouldn't give a name `std` to custom namespace.

Answer (score 3):

This is so much artificial:

```
namespace fred {
namespace std {  // A standard fred component

class string { // Something rather unlike the ::std::string
   // ...
};

} // namespace std
} // namespace fred
```

This Fred would not be able to explain why he did that to the whole team.

To answer your question: people omit first "::" because it is a habit, which saves time and  because it is easier to expect that when namespace is used anywhere, then such name is absolute, not relative.

Comment: Fred needs to get hit with a LART.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, you say that `std` is only an example. But to me it appears your question is only applicable to a case where somebody does something as evil as overriding `std`.

Let me provide another example:

```
namespace logging
{
    // Logs to local file
}

namespace server
{
    namespace logging
    {
        // Logs to remote destination
    }
}

namespace client
{
    namespace logging
    {
        // Logs to local file and to screen
    }
}
```

In this case, not prepending `::` results in default behavior.

Comment: This is an excellent reason why relative namespaces should be used in some circumstances, I definitely agree.

Comment: But in your class, what happens when someone creates a namespace 'server' in their namespace 'client' to refer to server related things that the client cares about?

Comment: @Omnifarious I just wanted to show that the answers heavily depend on the example you give for this question. Anyway: I'd say this would be nearly as evil as making up one's own std namespace. One could use "servercom" if it's about commmunication or "serverconf" for configuratione etc. instead of just "server".

Comment: So that means that nobody should ever name their sub-namespace name the same name as any global level namespace name?

Comment: No, this must not to be seen as law. As so often **it depends**...
Using std is probably always a bad idea. If you do definitely want to call your namespace the same as another, then you should carefully weigh out the benefits and problems that might arise from that.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of `std` I wouldn't assume any other namespace with the same name, same classes but different meaning.

In other cases, the leading `::` just looks ugly, and makes reading code more difficult (in my opinion). Namespace clashes are too rare to put the `::` in front of everything.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of code is written in the global namespace.  If someone really redefines ::std::, it won't matter how you refer to it in that kind of code.

Also, your scenario is both unlikely and easy to work around.  Firstly, the convention since there was a 'std' was that you don't use that name.  Secondly, if you were to encounter a package that defined the 'std' namespace, you just do this:

```
#include <package_name.hpp>

namespace package_name {
  using namespace std;
}

namespace my_app {
  class my_class : public package_name::class_of_something {};
}
```

Or something similar.  You might have to explicitly name ::std as std.  My point is this: people go about using the un-anchored 'std::' all the time because even the worst-case consequences aren't a big deal, and unlikely at that.

Answer (score 1):

In the same way that names prefixed with `_` are reserved, consider `std::` as good as reserved.

Comment: Though to be pedantic, not all names prefixed by an underscore are reserved.

Comment: Yes, not all. Should anyone be interested in the fully goriness, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)