# How do I use a Java-like C++ enum as a member variable of another class?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use the [solution for java-like enums in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1965344/79217).

My Problem is that I'm trying to use the enum as a member in another class.
So first we start with the familiar Planet enum:

```cpp
#ifndef PLANETS_H
#define PLANETS_H

class Planet {
  public:
    static const double G = 6.67300E-11;
    // Enum value DECLARATIONS - they are defined later
    static const Planet MERCURY;
    static const Planet VENUS;
    // ...

  private:
    double mass;   // in kilograms
    double radius; // in meters

  private:
    Planet(double mass, double radius) {
        this->mass = mass;
        this->radius = radius;
    }

  public:

    double surfaceGravity() {
        return G * mass / (radius * radius);
    }
};

// Enum value DEFINITIONS
// The initialization occurs in the scope of the class,
// so the private Planet constructor can be used.
const Planet Planet::MERCURY = Planet(3.303e+23, 2.4397e6);
const Planet Planet::VENUS = Planet(4.869e+24, 6.0518e6);

#endif // PLANETS_H
```

Then we have a `SolarSystem` object that takes `Planet` objects.

```cpp
#ifndef SOLARSYSTEM_H
#define SOLARSYSTEM_H

#include "Planets.h"
class SolarSystem {
  public:
    SolarSystem(int distance, const Planet& planet) {
        this->distance = distance;
        this->planet = planet;
    }

  private:
    int distance;   // in kilometers
    Planet planet;

};


#endif // SOLARSYSTEM_H
```

Now if we try to compile this we get the following errors:

```
SolarSystem.h: In constructor 'SolarSystem::SolarSystem(int, const Planet&)':
SolarSystem.h:7:53: error: no matching function for call to 'Planet::Planet()'
SolarSystem.h:7:53: note: candidates are:
Planets.h:17:5: note: Planet::Planet(double, double)
Planets.h:17:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
Planets.h:4:7: note: Planet::Planet(const Planet&)
Planets.h:4:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

The problem can be fixed by including an empty `Planet()` constructor.

I was wondering if that is the most appropriate fix or if there is a solution that does not involve an empty constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make `Planet planet` a reference and initialize it in the initializer list. Otherwise, C++ tries to make a copy of an instance of the `Planet` - precisely the thing that you wanted to avoid.

```
class SolarSystem {
public:
    SolarSystem(int distance, const Planet& planet)
    :   distance(distance)
    ,   planet(planet) {
    }

private:
    int distance;   // in kilometers
    const Planet& planet;

};
```

Comment: OK, next problem.

Let's say I have a setter in there: void setPlanet(const Planet& planet) { this->planet = planet; }

I can't use the initializer syntax there. How do I handle that?

Comment: @JamesOltmans If you need assignable values there, unfortunately, you will need to make `planet` a pointer. All variables in Java are "pointers", but in C++ you need to make it explicit. You could hide pointers behind member functions taking and returning references, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you use c++11, you can also use the Java-like C++ enum method that I described (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29594977/558366), which is basically a wrapper class around an int variable and allows you to use Planet almost as if it is an ordinary enum type (it supports casting to and from `int` and has the same size as `int`), but still has member functions, such as `planet.SurfaceGravity()`. It would allow your solar system header to compile (though you can and should remove the reference of the Planet argument in the constructor):

```
class SolarSystem {
  public:
    SolarSystem(int distance, Planet planet) {
        this->distance = distance;
        this->planet = planet;
    }

  private:
    int distance;   // in kilometers
    Planet planet;
};
```