# Is a class definition complete when it is passed to a base class?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I am trying to write a CRTP to contain a `static constexpr` of the derived type, since this is impossible to do with just one class. This code compiles fine in GCC, but clang complains that `Derived` is an incomplete type. Which one is right?

```
template<class T>
class Base {
public:
    static constexpr T a = T(1), b = T(20);
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> {
public:
    int x;
    constexpr Derived(int x) : x(x) {}
};
```

Comment: Be careful at Derived's constructor the local variable x and the member have the same name

Comment: I just want to point out that keeping derived objects as static inside the base class is not the best idea..

Comment: The only reason for doing it this way is because I can't put a `static constexpr` of the type `Derived` into `Derived`. I wanted to be able to do this: `Derived::a` instead of something like `Derived::constants::a`.

Comment: you can make a static method in derived that has a static object Derived that is returned.

Comment: You might want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928089/static-constexpr-member-of-same-type-as-class-being-defined), particularly [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32134757/3216312) states that a solution proposed there works on  GCC 4.9 and 5.1, as well as clang 3.4. So you might need no CRTP at all?

Comment: justification of compiler error will be like .... definition of Derived is not complete, at the point(Inside constructor) when an instance of it was requested in `Base<Derived>` class. `static constexpr T a = T(1), b = T(20);` , Now why GCC does not give an error is matter of investigation ..

Comment: why do you have it to be `constexpr`? it's seems classic for polymorphism

Comment: @Petr If you do that, you get issues with multiple linkage, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33177955/static-constexpr-of-class-inside-class-link-problems

Comment: @user975989, ok, I see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Derived` is incomplete at the point at which `Base<Derived>` is instantiated ([class.mem]/2), which happens right at definition time. You used `constexpr`, which necessitates an initializer as per [class.static.data]/3, and  when `Base<Derived>` is instantiated, so are the declarations of its static data members ([temp.inst]/3), which includes initializers. However, the initializers are attempting to create an object of incomplete type, which is ill-formed.

You can declare your member as `const` instead:

```
template<class T>
class Base {
public:
    static const T a;
};
template <typename T>
constexpr T Base<T>::a = T(1);
```

since the initializer is now at the definition, the instantiation of this initializer can be deferred until e.g. `Derived` is complete. [**Demo**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/rp5Y6eaFtPTPxl6j) with Clang.

Note that Clang doesn't yet treat `a` as `constexpr` because it fails to eagerly instantiate its definition. See bug [**#24541**](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=24541).

Comment: But then you can't do `static_assert(Derived::a.x == 1, "")`, which kind of defeats the purpose of `constexpr`.

Comment: @user975989 That appears to be a Clang bug.

Comment: @user975989 Found the DR and added it to the answer. (Funnily enough, the example used is much on point!)

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Why does this not cause multiple definitions as opposed to not using CTRP?

Comment: @user975989 What do you mean?

Comment: When I tried basically the same solution without using a template, I had the linker complain that the `constexpr`s were being defined multiple times, however this doesn't seem to be the case with this templated solution. The question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33177955/static-constexpr-of-class-inside-class-link-problems

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94347/discussion-between-columbo-and-user975989).