# C++ inherit class as static

Tags: c++

After reading through [How to write a Java-enum-like class with multiple data fields in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965249/how-to-write-a-java-enum-like-class-with-multiple-data-fields-in-c) I decided to give it a try and added some functionality to it. In order to abstract this functionality I've put it in a separate class `EnumClass<T>`. But since these abstracted features have to be static in the implementation but not in the original class I would need to do something like:

```
class Planet : public static EnumClass<Planet>
```

Which is not allowed. Is there some other way to do this? I got around it by adding a static instance of `EnumClass<Planet>` to `Planet`, but it is not really optimal:

```
template<class T, uint64_t S>
class EnumClass {
    public:
        const T elements[S];
        const uint64_t length = S;
        
        template<typename F>
        const T find(F lambda) const {
            for (int i = 0; i < S; i++) {
                if (lambda(elements[i])) {
                    return elements[i];
                }
            }
            return NULL;
        }
};

template <class T, class... U>
EnumClass(T, U...) -> EnumClass<T, 1 + sizeof...(U)>;

class Planet {  
  public: 
    static const Planet MERCURY;  
    static const Planet VENUS;
    
    static constexpr EnumClass ENUM = { &MERCURY, &VENUS };

  private: 
    double massValue;
    double radiusValue;

  private: 
    Planet(double massValue, double radiusValue) {  
        this->massValue = massValue;  
        this->radiusValue = radiusValue;
    } 

  public: 
    double mass() const {
        return this->massValue;
    }
    
    double radius() const {
        return this->radiusValue;
    }
    
    static const Planet* findByMass(double massValue) {
        return ENUM.find([massValue](const Planet * element) { return element->mass() == massValue; });
    }
    
    static const Planet* findByRadius(double radiusValue) {
        return ENUM.find([radiusValue](const Planet * element) { return element->radius() == radiusValue; });
    }
}; 

// Enum value DEFINITIONS 
const Planet Planet::MERCURY = Planet(3.303e+23, 2.4397e6);
const Planet Planet::VENUS = Planet(4.869e+24, 6.0518e6);
```

Comment: its unclear what this is supposed to mean `class Planet : public static EnumClass<Planet>` the keyword `static` has different meanings in different contexts, but what should it mean when used like that?

Comment: Same as usual just that all members of `EnumClass<Planet>` become static after inheritance.

Comment: why are not simply the members of `EnumClass<Planet>` static ?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/hhexx9rGv

Comment: Umm good question. I thought that they are then static in each instance of `EnumClass` independent of the template type, but that's obviously wrong^^ That was a bit dumb from my side :D

Comment: static members are per class not per template. `EnumClass<Planet>` is not the same class as `EnumClass<Foo>`

Comment: if all instantiations of `EnumClass` would share the static members then your approach with `EnumClass` as member wouldn't work as well

Comment: The current version of `EnumClass` doesn't have any `static` members^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want members of `EnumClass` to be static then just make them static. `static` as in `class Planet : public static EnumClass<Planet>` does not make sense. You cannot turn non-static members into static members like that.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

template<class T,size_t S>
class EnumClass {
    public:
        static const std::array<const T*,S> elements;
        static const size_t length = S;
        
        template<typename F>
        static const T* find(F lambda) {
            for (int i = 0; i < S; i++) {
                if (lambda(elements[i])) {
                    return elements[i];
                }
            }
            return NULL;
        }
};


class Planet : EnumClass<Planet,2> {  
  public: 
    static const Planet MERCURY;  
    static const Planet VENUS;
    
    //static constexpr EnumClass ENUM = { &MERCURY, &VENUS };

  private: 
    double massValue;
    double radiusValue;

  private: 
    Planet(double massValue, double radiusValue) {  
        this->massValue = massValue;  
        this->radiusValue = radiusValue;
    } 

  public: 
    double mass() const {
        return this->massValue;
    }
    
    double radius() const {
        return this->radiusValue;
    }
    
    static const Planet* findByMass(double massValue) {
        return find([massValue](const Planet * element) { return element->mass() == massValue; });
    }
    
    static const Planet* findByRadius(double radiusValue) {
        return find([radiusValue](const Planet * element) { return element->radius() == radiusValue; });
    }
}; 

// Enum value DEFINITIONS 
const Planet Planet::MERCURY = Planet(3.303e+23, 2.4397e6);
const Planet Planet::VENUS = Planet(4.869e+24, 6.0518e6);

template <>
const std::array<const Planet*,2> EnumClass<Planet,2>::elements{{&Planet::MERCURY,&Planet::VENUS}};
```